# How can I write a vey long LP problem in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, multline

I am trying to write a very long LP problem in LaTeX, 5-7 lines or so. I tried to use multline but it does not compile for some reason.

This is my code:

```
 \begin{multline} 
 Min \quad Z = 111x_{11} + 111x_{12} + 109.25x_{13} + 111x_{14} + 113x_{15}\\
 +107.25x_{21} + 119.5x_{22} + 107.7x_{23} + 103.75x_{24} + 109.7x_{25}\\
 + x_{13} + x_{23} + x_{33} + x_{34} + x_{35}\\
 + x_{14} + x_{24} + x_{34} + x_{44} + x_{45]\\
 + x_{15} + x_{25} + x_{35} + x_{45} + x_{55}\\
 + x_{16} + x_{26} + x_{36} + x_{46} + x_{56}\\
 + x_{17} + x_{27} + x_{37} + x_{47} + x_{57}\\
 \end{multline}
```

It compiles if I wrote the objective function up till x_{35}, but then if I were to complete it doesn't.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: You mistyped with `x_{45]`. it should be `x_{45}`. With that fixed, it runs fine for me

Comment: Another note, I don't think you want the `\\ ` on the last line.

Comment: @egreg - The OP's immediate problem is indeed due to a simple typo. However, as I try to explain in the answer I posted a couple of minutes ago, he/she should also give serious consideration to *not* using a `multiline` environment for the 7-line equation. A nested `equation`/`aligned` solution would seem far more appropriate.

Comment: I wanted to use align, but I didn't know how, thanks anyways

Comment: write as `c'x` please don't use this format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to replacing `x_{45]` with `x_{45}`, you may want to think about replacing the `multline` environment with a nested `equation`/`aligned` environment.

Separately, unless you're forced to do so by some (awful and highly idiosyncratic typographic convention), don't write `Min`; instead, write `\min`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' env.
\begin{document}
\noindent
Combined \texttt{equation}/\texttt{aligned} solution:
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}[b]
\min Z &= 111x_{11} + 111x_{12} + 109.25x_{13} + 111x_{14} + 113x_{15}\\
&\quad +107.25x_{21} + 119.5x_{22} + 107.7x_{23} + 103.75x_{24} + 109.7x_{25}\\
&\quad + x_{13} + x_{23} + x_{33} + x_{34} + x_{35}\\
&\quad + x_{14} + x_{24} + x_{34} + x_{44} + x_{45}\\
&\quad + x_{15} + x_{25} + x_{35} + x_{45} + x_{55}\\
&\quad + x_{16} + x_{26} + x_{36} + x_{46} + x_{56}\\
&\quad + x_{17} + x_{27} + x_{37} + x_{47} + x_{57}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

\bigskip\noindent
\texttt{multline} solution:
\begin{multline}
\min Z = 111x_{11} + 111x_{12} + 109.25x_{13} + 111x_{14} + 113x_{15}\\
 +107.25x_{21} + 119.5x_{22} + 107.7x_{23} + 103.75x_{24} + 109.7x_{25}\\
 + x_{13} + x_{23} + x_{33} + x_{34} + x_{35}\\
 + x_{14} + x_{24} + x_{34} + x_{44} + x_{45}\\
 + x_{15} + x_{25} + x_{35} + x_{45} + x_{55}\\
 + x_{16} + x_{26} + x_{36} + x_{46} + x_{56}\\
 + x_{17} + x_{27} + x_{37} + x_{47} + x_{57}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up request, i.e., to make the entries "even more aligned" across all seven rows. It's certainly *possible* to do this, say with the help of an `array` environment -- see below. IMNSHO, though, you're *not* doing your readers a favor at all with such notation. If this were my paper, I'd use a `\sum` directive to indicate that simple summation over 25 variables is to be performed.

(Note that, in keeping with the OP's writing in the follow-up requests, the subscript sequencing is quite different in the following code from what was used in the original answer.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Combined \texttt{equation}/\texttt{aligned} solution:
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}[b]
\min Z &= 111x_{11} + 111x_{12} + 109.25x_{13} + 111x_{14} + 113x_{15}\\
&\quad +107.25x_{21} + 119.5x_{22} + 107.7x_{23} + 103.75x_{24} + 109.7x_{25}\\
&\quad + x_{13} + x_{23} + x_{33} + x_{34} + x_{35}\\
&\quad + x_{14} + x_{24} + x_{34} + x_{44} + x_{45}\\
&\quad + x_{15} + x_{25} + x_{35} + x_{45} + x_{55}\\
&\quad + x_{16} + x_{26} + x_{36} + x_{46} + x_{56}\\
&\quad + x_{17} + x_{27} + x_{37} + x_{47} + x_{57}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

\bigskip\noindent
``even more aligned'': combined \texttt{equation}, \texttt{aligned}, and \texttt{array}
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}[b]
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}[b]{@{} r*{6}{Cr} @{}}
\min Z &=& 111x_{11} &+& 111x_{12} &+& 109.25x_{13} &+& 111x_{14} &+& 113x_{15}\\
&+&107.25x_{21} &+& 119.5x_{22} &+& 107.7x_{23} &+& 103.75x_{24} &+& 109.7x_{25}\\
&+& x_{31} &+& x_{32} &+& x_{33} &+& x_{34} &+& x_{35}\\
&+& x_{31} &+& x_{42} &+& x_{43} &+& x_{44} &+& x_{45}\\
&+& x_{51} &+& x_{52} &+& x_{53} &+& x_{54} &+& x_{55}\\
&+& x_{61} &+& x_{62} &+& x_{63} &+& x_{64} &+& x_{65}\\
&+& x_{71} &+& x_{72} &+& x_{73} &+& x_{74} &+& x_{75}\\
\end{array}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

\bigskip\noindent
\verb+\sum+ notation to replace rows 3 to 7:
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}[b]
\min Z &= 111x_{11} + 111x_{12} + 109.25x_{13} + 111x_{14} + 113x_{15}\\
&\quad +107.25x_{21} + 119.5x_{22} + 107.7x_{23} + 103.75x_{24} + 109.7x_{25}\\
&\quad+ \smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{i=3,\dots,7;\\j=1,\dots,5}}} x_{ij}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay now I want to make them even more align, in terms of variables. What commands do I need to use?

Comment: @Anonymous - Please clarify what you mean by "even more align".

Comment: Like I want for every x_{ij} variable to be exactly underneath each other. Where i=1,...,7 and j=1,...,5

Comment: By the way, I find the switch in notation between the first two lines and the final five lines to be quite disconcerting. For instance, I would have expected the 5 variables in row 3 to be named `x_{31}`, `x_{32}`, `x_{33}`, `x_{34}`, and `x_{35}`, and *not* `x_{13}`, `x_{23}`, `x_{33}`, `x_{34}`, and `x_{35}`. With your notation, it's really not so obvious why the variable `x_{13}` occurs both in row 1 and in row 3, or why `x_{23}` occurs both in row 2 and in row 3. Please advise if you really intend this type of row and column notation.